# animating a jQuery progress bar with button clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation, progress-bar

I'm trying to get my progress bar animated. I'd like it to smoothly transition in between the starting and destination values, but only be initiated by clicking the continue button.

The code I currently have works great, but when clicking forward or backward, it brings you directly to the values:

```
//PROGRESS BAR
$( "#progress" ).progressbar(
{
    value: 0
})
.data("value","0");

//CONTINUE BUTTON
$("#cont").button();

//UPDATING PROGRESS BAR WHEN CONTINUE BUTTON CLICKED
$("#cont").click(function() 
{
    var currValue = $( "#progress" ).data("value");
    currValue = parseInt(currValue) ? parseInt(currValue) : 0;
    if(currValue <= 100) 
    {
        $( "#progress" ).progressbar({
          value: currValue+25
        }).data("value",currValue+25);
    }    
});
```

I've seen a couple examples of animated progressbars, but none by clicking and stopping when a certain value was reached.

I'd like something similar to this awful pseudo code..lol

```
if(progress.value === 0 && continue button clicked)
{
    while(progress.value != 25)
    {
        progressbar.animate(progress.value + 1)
    }
}
else if(progress.value === 25 && continue button clicked)
{
    while(progress.value != 50)
    {
        progressbar.animate(progress.value + 1)
    }
}
etc. etc.
```

Anyone tried something similar?

Comment: I believe [I have](http://users.telenet.be/tive/). Hold down the "roll dice" button to see the effect. Disable it on the options panel. Let me know if it is something similar you seek.

Comment: While that's an impressive program, it's not quite the effect I'm looking for. As I said, I'd like it to start at 0 then, the user clicks the continue button and the progress bar bar smoothly slides to the value of 25 and so on. Think of it more like 4 individual 'slides' using the progress bar to visualize which slide or step you're currently on.

Comment: With "something similar" I mean the idea behind the start/stop, enable/disable, and fx functionality which is the simple math, all in one `progressbar` object.

Comment: something like this [http://jsfiddle.net/8u76B/](http://jsfiddle.net/8u76B/)? it only have a cont button (+25)

Comment: Actually, I'm still having some issues. The code runs beautifully in JSfiddle on JQ 1.9.1, but I'm running jQuery 1.10.4 locally and when I copy the code over it no longer works. I would assume it would be because something between the 2 versions was deprecated. anyone know what it is? @AbrahamUribe

Comment: [http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example using option - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FRX7E/1/)
I updated the fiddle to manage the state of the buttons as well.

```
if ( target.is( "#next" ) ) {
    progressbar.progressbar( "option", {
      value: progressPercent+= 10
    });
  } else if ( target.is( "#previous" ) ) {
    progressbar.progressbar( "option", {
      value: progressPercent-= 10
    });
  }
```

This doesn't check for any limits so you can go below zero and above 100 with the progressPercent variable.  That's any easy fix thouogh.